# Using threads to speed up tasks

Tags: c++, multithreading

First time using threads this way (new to programming) and I assume I understood wrong on how threads work, I know it allows you to perform several actions at the same time, but does it also not reduce the workload if you are running multiple threads?

Shouldn't running 2 threads doing 2 seperate things complete the task twice as fast? (using multicore cpu's obviously)

The below task for example, running just 1 task in 1 thread takes 2~seconds, running 2 tasks in 2 threads takes 4 seconds instead of what I assumed would still take 2seconds.

```
void func2(int x, int y) {} //do nothing
void func1(int x, int y) {} //do nothing
void line1() {
for (int x = 0; x < 4100; x++) {
    func1(x, 100);
    cout<< "1 " << x << endl;
}
}

void line2() {
for (int x = 0; x < 4100; x++) {
    func2(x, 200);
    cout<< "1 " << x << endl;
}
}

int main()
 {
std::thread t1(line1);
std::thread t2(line2);

    //int as;
    //cin >> as;
return 0;
 }
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? I don't know if c++ is just using 1 core for all threads? I'm only running on 24% cpu usage so I doubt its because all 4 cores are fully used or something. This shouldn't be the case when I'm at 24%, no? Unless the scheduler has assigned all 4 cores to something else when I'm running my code.

Comment: The stream inserters are synchronizing behind your back. Change your functions to do more work and less IO to see more parallelism.

Comment: Are you building a 'release' build? if so, `func1` and `func2` calls are probably optimized away.  You are probably only doing console IO.  The only synchronization would be in the OS write function.  I am not aware of any synchronization in iostreams. Recommend you change `line2`'s output to "2  ".

Comment: Make sure you join your threads. The way the code is now, the threads are destroyed immediately after construction (because main exits and their scope is exited).  `t1.join(); t2.join();` will block until both threads exit.

Comment: change endl to '\n'.  This will allow the streambuf's to do their job. Remember endl appends an new line and flushes the stream which will call the OS and it will serialize IO.  You'll get more work between flush operations (which will only happen when the streambuf decides it's time).